# Sending JSON from PHP to Javascript (undefined)

Tags: javascript, php, html, json

I sent JSON object from PHP to JS, and in HTML I get the answer "undefined". Why?

PHP file ***server.php***

```
$filename = "osoba.json";
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
$json_decoded = json_decode($file);
$json_encoded = json_encode($json_decoded);
echo $json_encoded;
```

JS file ***script.js***

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        var mojNiz = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mojNiz.ime;
    }
};

xhr.open("GET", "server.php", true);
xhr.send();
```

and HTML ***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Pocetna stranica</title

</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo">

    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

also have a JSON string ***osoba.json***

```
{"zaposleni":[{"ime":"Dunjica","prezime":"Markovic"},{"ime":"Jovan","prezime":"Markovic"},{"ime":"Marija","prezime":"Markovic"}]}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for you to first decode and then encode the file in php before you send it? Is there a reason you use XMLHttpRequest instead of fetch?

Comment: You get `undefined` because the top-level object defined by that JSON doesn't have an `ime` property. It has a `zaposleni` property that refers to an array of objects, and those objects have `ime` properties, but not the top-level object.

Comment: In the PHP code, why parse the JSON from the file, then re-stringify it? Do you want to ensure it's valid before sending it, or...?

Comment: Yes, I want to ensure, no special reason, but it's not working eatherway...

Comment: I deleted a "zaposleni" from .json file, and still get "undefined"

Comment: Could you `console.log(mojNiz)`, look in the console and show us what data you receive.

Comment: I get this message "script.js:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: mojNiz is not defined
    at script.js:18"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My friend, "How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?)" this still doesn't resolve my problem. I try another code in .php file, and everything and still not working...

Comment: @DanijelS - Read the answers there carefully. The issue is that you're not using the correct code to access the data. The answers there describe how to access data in various object structures. For one thing, there are multiple `ime` properties, not just one. In the JSON quoted in the question, for instance, once you parse it you'd access the **first** `ime` property via `mojNiz.zaposleni[0].ime`. But more likely, you want a look.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, I understand it now. Thanks